# Can cucumber.yml be moved to a different folder?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Currently I have `cucumber.yml` in the root folder of my project. This is what my folder structure looks like right now:

```
root
|-->config    
|    |-->cucumber_config
|          |->data
|          |->environments   
|                  
|-->features
     |-->step_definitions
     |-->support
           |-->pages
```

I need to move `cucumber.yml` inside `cucumber_config` if possible.

Is there a setting or anything I need to set to allow this?

Your help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the cucumber source code:

```
# Locates cucumber.yml file. The file can end in .yml or .yaml,
# and be located in the current directory (eg. project root) or
# in a .config/ or config/ subdirectory of the current directory.
def cucumber_file
  @cucumber_file ||= Dir.glob('{,.config/,config/}cucumber{.yml,.yaml}').first
end
```

Therefore the answer is "No" unless you change the implementation.

Comment: I can move it into config but not config/cucumber_config. Thanks.